# Winform Installer Register each version

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, installation

I build my own Winform and packaging as msi installer with VisualStudio Installer project.

Installer works really well but there's a problem.

Currently I upload patch hourly because there's lots of bug to fix. so users who uses my winapp needs to run installer when updated.

When user runs my installer, on control panel, my program listed on there with each version like following image.

[image]

**I wish to remove old version and keep newest version on the list.**

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

This is my installer's property. and I manually config 'Version' property for control version.

Added : I keep RemovePreviousVersions as false because I wish to keep installer settings of "User Desktop Shortcut" and "User Programs Menu Shortcut"

Comment: set `RemovePreviousVersions` to true and it should work fine, installer settings of "User Desktop Shortcut" and "User Programs Menu Shortcut", what are they and where are the settings?

Comment: @kennyzx I found the problem when I hold it on start menu 
when I do patch, that shortcut doesn't work. I guess because Desktop and Programs Menu shortcut regenerated when reinstall package with RemovePReviousVersions property.